# Drupal 6 : Redirect after form submit to display a block

Tags: php, forms, drupal-6

Its been some time away from Drupal so here it goes:

I have a form that takes the user input (a keyword) and after that should display the latest tweets based on the keyword. Hence i am using twitter pull module..

```
function tweet_message_form() {
    $form['tweet_message'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Fetch Tweets'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('tweet_message', 'Keyword'),
    );

    //Submit button:
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Save Message'),
    );

    return $form;
}
```

Now inside the `tweet_message_form_submit($form, &$form_state)` function what should i write?
I want to display a block when the form is submitted.

The block code is

```
<?php if (function_exists('twitter_pull_render')) { print twitter_pull_render('**keyword_entered**', '', 10); } ?>
```

I want to pass the value of keyword to this block from the form submit.So what should be the code inside the form submit? Not the exact code but some hints or tutorial links.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to create a page (or just URL) to go to after you submit the form.  let's say it's at "/example/thankyou"

In your function where you define the form, you can say:

```
  $form["#redirect"] = "example/thankyou";
```

Or, in your submit handler, you can say:

```
  drupal_goto("example/thankyou");
```

To pass information, in your submit handler you could always store the value in a SESSION variable, or just make it part of the URL...

```
  drupal_goto("example/thankyou/THEVALUEGOESHERE");
```

Comment: perfect sense..but my question was how do i pass the entered keyword to the block? also in the page say "example/thankyou" how do i display the block?..i could use module_invoke but not sure though..make sense?

Comment: In your drupal blocks administration, make the block appear on the page, only for the URL "example/thankyou/*".  I edited my answer to show how you could pass information along.

Comment: If you are asking how do you create a "block" in Drupal, check out the hook_block() function: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6

Answer (score 1):

```
$form["#redirect"] = "example/thankyou";
```

drupal_goto() may not save all data